# Flatten list of nested namedtuples to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flatten, namedtuple

**Sample**:

```
import collections

A = collections.namedtuple('A', 'a b c')
B = collections.namedtuple('B', 'x y z w')

L = [A(a='CODE1',  b=B(x=2, y='u', z='v', w='a'), c=10),
     A(a='CODE2',  b=B(x=4, y='h', z='r', w='b'), c=30)]
```

I have list of namedtuples and I want to flatten it, replace nested namedtuple `B` by values of `b`.

What I try:

First  I try convert both namedtuples to dictionaries and merge them, but problem was remove original `b` values in dict comprehension and also ordering is wrong:

```
t = [{k: v for k, v in {**x.b._asdict(), **x._asdict()}.items() 
      if k != 'b'} for x in L]
print (t)

[{'x': 2, 'y': 'u', 'z': 'v', 'w': 'a', 'a': 'CODE1', 'c': 10}, 
 {'x': 4, 'y': 'h', 'z': 'r', 'w': 'b', 'a': 'CODE2', 'c': 30}]
```

Another solution working like need, but it is a bit complicated in my opinion - I prefer list comprehension solution:

```
t = []
for x in L:
    out = {}
    d = x._asdict()
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, tuple):
            d1 = v._asdict()
            for k1, v1 in d1.items():
                out[k1] = v1
        else:
            out[k] = v
    t.append(out)

print (t)

[{'a': 'CODE1', 'x': 2, 'y': 'u', 'z': 'v', 'w': 'a', 'c': 10}, 
 {'a': 'CODE2', 'x': 4, 'y': 'h', 'z': 'r', 'w': 'b', 'c': 30}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With complex `list` comprehensions and `OrderedDict` object:

```
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

...
res = [OrderedDict(chain.from_iterable(
                   v._asdict().items() if isinstance(v, (A, B)) else [(k, v)]
                   for k, v in nt._asdict().items())) for nt in L]
print(res)
```

The output:

```
[OrderedDict([('a', 'CODE1'),
              ('x', 2),
              ('y', 'u'),
              ('z', 'v'),
              ('w', 'a'),
              ('c', 10)]),
 OrderedDict([('a', 'CODE2'),
              ('x', 4),
              ('y', 'h'),
              ('z', 'r'),
              ('w', 'b'),
              ('c', 30)])]
```

The "trick" is to obtain a *flat* sequence of tuples passed to `OrderedDict(...)` (top-level tuples is wrapped `[(k, v)]` to *agree on* potential nested tuples)

Comment: So ordering in output is problem?

Comment: @jezrael, I'm afraid that to keep the most original order you'd need to stick to the OrderedDict. See my update

Comment: No problem, `OrderedDict` is nice.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no ordering in a dictionary. If ordering is important for you, you might consider using an OrderedDict from the Collections package (see the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html)). Btw, it seems namedtuples are built on OrderedDicts...

Concerning your question, maybe you can create another type of namedtuples in order to force your order:

```py
AB = collections.namedtuple('AB', 'a x y z w c')
```

and then you can explicitly transcode as desired:

```py
list(map( lambda l: AB(l.a, l.b.x, l.b.y, l.b.z, l.b.w, l.c) , L))
```

and if for some reason you don't want to explicitly write B's field, you can automate a bit with

```py
AB(L[0].a,*[v for v in L[0].b._asdict()],L[0].c)
```

Edit to embed comments and answers to comments ------------

```py
import collections
from itertools import chain

A = collections.namedtuple('A', 'a b c')
B = collections.namedtuple('B', 'x y z w')

L = [A(a='CODE1',  b=B(x=2, y='u', z='v', w='a'), c=10),
     A(a='CODE2',  b=B(x=4, y='h', z='r', w='b'), c=30)]

AB = collections.namedtuple('AB',
" ".join(chain.from_iterable(
        v._asdict().keys() if isinstance(v, (A, B)) else [k] for k,v in L[0]._asdict().items()) 
    )
)
LL = [AB._make(dict(
    chain.from_iterable( 
        v._asdict().items() if isinstance(v, (A, B)) else [(k, v)] for k, v in nt._asdict().items())
    )) for nt in L] 
print (LL)
```

That's all I can see for now, hopes this helps.

Comment: Solution seems nice, but is possible create it more dynamic, without use `a x y z w c` ?

Comment: Combined with the very elegant solution from RomanPerekhrest

`[AB._make(dict(chain.from_iterable(
            v._asdict().items() if isinstance(v, (A, B)) else [(k, v)]
            for k, v in nt._asdict().items()))) for nt in L]`

Comment: OK, but how created `AB` dynamic, without typing `'a x y z w c'` ?

Comment: Something like :

`AB = collections.namedtuple('AB',
" ".join(chain.from_iterable(
        v._asdict().keys() if isinstance(v, (A, B)) else [k] for k,v in L[0]._asdict().items()) 
    )
)`